# how to split Json data present in one column of table in mssql for generating reports using ssrs

Tags: json, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to generate reports using mssql… in SSRS …. in one column of table there is json data... what is the effective way to split the data from column to make it as normal data....

JSON

```
personalInfo
firstName : "ALOK"
middleName : "KUMAR"
lastName : "TIWARI"
motherMaidenName : null
initial : null
nationality : "Indian"
gender : "Male"
dob : "1988-Aug-04"
uniqueIdNumber : "ALXPT9685Q"
uniqueIdNumber_o : null
govt_id : null
dobForAge : "04-08-1988"
maritalStatus : null
birthLocation : null
bloodGroup : null
pancard_no : null
aadhaarcard_no : null
permanentAddress
address : "VILLAGE SITAKUND"
countryState : "Uttar Pradesh"
city : "Ballia"
pinCode : "277001"
stdCodeLandline : "--"
mobile : "91-8867836324"
mobile_o : "-"
emailId1 : "alokumart26@gmail.com"
emailId2 : ""
testCity : "Bangalore"
emergency_contact_no : "-"
passport_no : null
communicationAddress
address : "Bellandur"
countryState : "Karnataka"
city : "Bangalore"
pinCode : "560103"
stdCodeLandline : null
mobile : null
mobile_o : null
emailId1 : null
emailId2 : null
testCity : null
emergency_contact_no : null
passport_no : null
experience
category : "Experienced"
experienceDetailsList
joiningPeriod : "1"
currentSalary : "2.6"
expectedSalary : "5"
source : "Recruiter"
sourceName : "nilabh upadhyay"
preferredLocation : null
workedInCompany : null
workedInCompanyTime : null
qualification
qualificationLevelToDetailsMap
historyArrears : "1"
standingArrears : "1"
universityRegnNo : "2536987"
gapInEducation : "Yes"
yrsOfGap : "2"
knowForeignLanguage : null
foreignLanguages : null
languageProficiency : null
trainingDetails
additionalDetails : null
flexibleCandidate : null
hasValidPassport : null
preferredLocations : null
questionsAnswersMap : null
addlInfoQ4 : null
Disclaimer : null
Search:
```

how should I proceed with json data in my column to generate reports... should I create separate tables for each json obects.?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not a supported data structure for SSRS. I would recommend loading the data into a table or tables first. You can use most databases, but SQL Server has the best compatibility.

Comment: how should i proceed with splitting data from json column to another table.?

Comment: Explaining how to parse JSON is too broad. It's up to you how you want to go about it. You can find an existing tool or write your own implementation.